# What is the min # of moves to sort an array from 1 to n?

Tags: algorithms, proof-techniques, sorting, lower-bounds

Problem: You are required to sort an array with numbers from 1 to n. You can do a "move", which means choosing one element and moving it to
any place you want (insert to any place, not swap). Prove the minimum number of "moves" to sort the array is `n - k`, where `k = the length of the longest increasing subsequence`.

Ex: array is `[1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 7, 6]`

Longest increasing subsequence is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]`, which is of length `5`. Hence, the answer is `7 - 5 = 2 moves`. You move numbers `5` and `7` to the correct spots.

I'd like a proof / intuition on why this has to be the minimum # of moves.

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Closely related questions: [1](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23251/find-the-minimum-amount-of-swaps-to-sort-array), [2](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16400/maximum-number-of-inversions-that-can-be-removed-by-swapping-two-elements).

Answer (score 8):

There is an invariant that each move can only increase the number in your longest increasing subsequence by at most 1.

If your initial array has $k$ values in its longest increasing subsequence, you need $n-k$ moves at least to get it sorted. 
This shows $n-k$ moves is necessary.

Comment: This is really nice. It took me longer to think about why the invariant is true; for anyone like me I would suggest thinking about the move as 2 moves: a deletion and an insertion, and how the length of the LIS can be affected by either.

Answer (score -1):

Given answer is wrong because for example -
let the given array is

```
    3 5 7 1 9 8
```

In the first step, 1 is removed and placed at first position, as a consequence the array becomes

```
    1 3 5 7 9 8
```

In the second step, 9 is removed and placed at the last position in the array, as a consequence the array becomes

```
    1 3 5 7 8 9
```

The array is now sorted. It took 2 steps to sort the array. You have to find out the minimum number of steps required to make the array sorted.

Comment: In this case $k = 4$ (3,5,7,9) so $n-k=2$. I don’t see where the problem lies.